# How do I add Auto Increment to Existing SQL ID Primary Key?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have an empty table that I thought was auto increment until I tried adding my first record. That's when SQL told me this:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID', table 'DB_9CF886_mcl959.dbo.Posts'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

So I tried to add the identity to it:

```sql
alter table dbo.Posts ADD ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) CONSTRAINT PK_Posts1 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED;
```

That gave me this error:

> Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'ID' in table 'dbo.Posts' is specified more than once.

I could drop the table and recreate it, but I'd like to know how to FIX IT to add the identity to the ID column.

Screenshot of database: [dbo.Posts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiz6w.png)

Comment: You should always make your columns `NOT NULL` unless you have a good reason otherwise, btw.

Comment: @Dai - I think so. Basically, I cannot use the current `ID` column then. Right?

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing - I could swear that `IDENTITY` could be added to an existing column but I guess not - HOWEVER, you _can_ still use a `SEQUENCE` with an existing column - which will achieve the same effect.

Comment: I've just posted my answer that demonstrates how to use a `SEQUENCE` object to make an existing column behave like an `IDENTITY` column without dropping any objects or losing any data or breaking any referential-integrity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it's true that you cannot add `IDENTITY` to an existing column, and that adding `IDENTITY` to an existing table means adding a new column - it's also true that you don't need to use `IDENTITY` - nor do you need to `DROP` anything either.

Instead, `ALTER` your existing `ID` column to use a `SEQUENCE` object for new values - which has (effectively) the same end-result as `IDENTITY` - but this way it will preserve your existing `ID` column values, preserve foreign-key references, and preserve your `CLUSTERED` index without needing a table rebuild.

Do this:

```sql
SET XACT_ABORT ON;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

DECLARE @baseId int = ( SELECT ISNULL( MAX( ID ), 0 ) FROM dbo.Posts ) + 1;

-- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.PostsIdSequence START WITH @baseId INCREMENT BY 1;

ALTER TABLE dbo.Posts
    ADD CONSTRAINT DF_Posts_Sequence DEFAULT NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.PostsIdSequence FOR "ID";

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Comment: Awesome script ! +1

Answer (score 3):

Below is an example that uses `SWITCH` to move data into another table of identical schema that already has the `IDENTITY`.

```
--create sample table and data
CREATE TABLE dbo.AddIdentityExample(
      IncrementalColumn int NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_AddIdentityExample PRIMARY KEY
    , OtherData varchar(20) NULL
    );
CREATE INDEX idx_AddIdentityExample_OtherData
    ON dbo.AddIdentityExample(OtherData);
INSERT INTO dbo.AddIdentityExample VALUES
      (1, 'Sample data one')
    , (2, 'Sample data two')
    , (3, 'Sample data three');
GO

SET XACT_ABORT ON;
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN;
    --create staging table with same schema, indexes, and constraints
    CREATE TABLE dbo.AddIdentityExampleStaging(
          IncrementalColumn int IDENTITY NOT NULL --IDENTITY column property added
            CONSTRAINT PK_AddIdentityExampleStaging PRIMARY KEY
        , OtherData varchar(20) NULL
        );
    CREATE INDEX idx_AddIdentityExampleStaging_OtherData
        ON dbo.AddIdentityExampleStaging(OtherData);

    --move data from source table into new table
    ALTER TABLE dbo.AddIdentityExample
        SWITCH TO dbo.AddIdentityExampleStaging;
    DROP TABLE dbo.AddIdentityExample;
    --rename table
    EXEC sp_rename
          @objname = N'dbo.AddIdentityExampleStaging'
        , @newname = N'AddIdentityExample'
        , @objtype = 'OBJECT';
    --rename constraints
    EXEC sp_rename
          @objname = N'dbo.PK_AddIdentityExampleStaging'
        , @newname = N'PK_AddIdentityExample'
        , @objtype = 'OBJECT';
    --rename indexes
    EXEC sp_rename
          @objname = N'dbo.AddIdentityExample.idx_AddIdentityExampleStaging_OtherData'
        , @newname = N'idx_AddIdentityExampleStaging_OtherData'
        , @objtype = N'INDEX';
    --seed IDENTITY with current max column value
    DBCC CHECKIDENT(N'dbo.AddIdentityExample');
    COMMIT;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK;
    THROW;
END CATCH;
GO
```

Comment: Great answer. `BEGIN CATCH IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK;` is not necessary if you have `XACT_ABORT ON`